# How convert a row in csv to array of double?

Tags: c#

I have the following data:

1,1,1,1,1,1

I want to read that line and covert it into array of ints or some other type.

Is there a one line solution to do that?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = "1,1,1,1,1,1".Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

In case your text includes some spaces

```
var arr = Regex.Matches("1,1,1,1,1,1", @"\d+")
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m => m.Value)
                    .ToArray();
```